# How do I stop one more file with same name (having different case) getting created in git stage

Tags: git

Because of few earlier commits with git ignorecase not handled properly, we have file named `File_XYZ.xml` on server repository whereas when we fetch it to our local repository, we have file named `file_xyz.xml`.

Now, if we change anything in `file_xyz.xml`, it shows me two files in the unstaged area of git, as `File_XYZ.xml` and `file_xyz.xml`.

If I run `git add -A`, only `file_xyz.xml` gets into the staged area and I cannot undo the changes to file `File_XYZ.xml` with `git checkout File_XYZ.xml` as it says `pathspec File_XYZ.xml did not match any file(s) known to git`.

If I go on commit and push, it fails saying you have unstaged changes. So, I had to workaround this to get this commit in another branch, head reset this branch to previous commit, merge the change to this branch and then push.

Any help to resolve this issue is appreciated. Both server and local systems are running Windows OS.

Comment: This link may also help you: http://www.woodcp.com/2013/01/git-unite-fix-case-sensitive-file-paths-on-windows/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're on Windows and pushing to a Linux remote.

Try the steps below:

1. Delete the file
2. Commit the deletion
3. Push the deletion commit
4. Create the file again with the right name
5. Commit the file
6. Push the file

**Why is this happening?**

Because Windows does not make difference between upper or lower case letters but Linux does! So keep in mind to not name files equally no matter the letters case.

**Update 1:**

You may need to delete and clone the repository again after step 3 before continue to step 4.

Comment: Thank you @Marcelo for the reply. The server might be running on Linux OS. Definitely, the solution suggested by you would work.

Comment: @Manoj nice to know! Consider mark this as an answer, please! :) Good luck!